# <a> link puts page name at end of url

Tags: html, github-pages

Sorry if the title is confusing, I wasn't exactly sure how to word this.

Basically what I want to do is make a link, simple enough. The page is tylerofcinema.github.io and if I make a link to say, google.com the url that I get is tylerofcinema.github.io/google.com.

Code is in a repo [here](https://github.com/tylerofcinema/tylerofcinema.github.io), let me know if there is any clarification needed.

Thanks, Diego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not include the protocol of the url, causing the href to think it needs to open a page in the same directory.

Try adding `http://` (or `https://`) to your href and it will open the specified url.

```
 <a target="_blank" href="https://tylerofcinema.github.io/r/twitter"><button class="homesmb">Twitter</button></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

should be a simple syntax error.

My suggestion would be to change the url to the full address like http://www.google.com so that the browser understands you mean the actual google server and not something else. give it a try

Answer (score 1):

just add `//` before the start of the link, it should work